# How to split object (nested) into multiple columns in Elasticsearch / Kibana data table visualization

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have a nested object indexed in elasticsearch (7.10) and I need to visualize it with a kibana table. The problem is that kibana throws in the values from the nested field which have the same name in one column.

Part of the index:

```
{
  "index" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "data1" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "Details" : {
          "type" : "nested",
          "properties" : {
            "Amount" : {
              "type" : "float"
            },
            "Currency" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "DetailType" : {
              "type" : "keyword"
            },
            "Price" : {
              "type" : "float"
            },
            "Quantity" : {
              "type" : "float"
            },
            "TotalAmount" : {
              "type" : "float"
             .......
```

The problem in the table:

[image]

How can I get three rows named Details each with one split term (e.g DetailType: "start_fee")?

Update:
I could query the nested object in the console:

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "Details",
      "query": {
       "bool": {
       "must": [
        { "match": { "Details.DetailType": "energybased_fee"   }}

      ]
    }
  },
  "inner_hits": {
}
}}}
```

But how can I visualize in the table only the "inner_hits" value?